# Command to check HDFS file is compressed or not

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, hdfs, gzip

Using command "`file <filename>`" in linux displays whether the file is compressed or not. How to achieve this for a file residing in HDFS file system?

```
file 620591952596020.gz
620591952596020.gz: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)

file 269146229598756
269146229598756: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

This will help me to avoid compressing a file (GZip) which is already compressed as part of Shell script invoked via Apache Oozie.

```
#!/bin/bash
HDFS_IN_PATH=$1;
IS_COMPRESS_FILE=true;

for archiveDir in 'ARCHIVE1' 'ARCHIVE2' ;
do
    HDFS_OUT_PATH=${HDFS_IN_PATH}/$archiveDir;

    for ls_entry in $(hdfs dfs -ls -C "$HDFS_IN_PATH"/$archiveDir);
    do
        fileAbsPath=$ls_entry;
        jobName=$(basename "${fileAbsPath}");

        if (hadoop fs -test -f "$fileAbsPath") ; then
            echo "Its not a directory ${fileAbsPath}"
            continue;
        fi

        for file in $(hdfs dfs -ls -C "$fileAbsPath");
        do
            filename=$(basename "${file}");

            if [ "$IS_COMPRESS_FILE" = true ]; then

              if(<<***COMMAND TO CHECK HDFS FILE ${file} IS COMPRESSED***>>); then
                  echo "File Name: ${file} is already compressed.."
                  continue;
              fi

              hadoop fs -cat "${file}" | gzip | hadoop fs -put - "${file}".gz;

              echo "Successfully compressed file..!";
            fi
        done

        hadoop archive -archiveName "${jobName}".har -p "${HDFS_OUT_PATH}" "${jobName}" "${HDFS_OUT_PATH}";
    done
done
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196774/5372462

Comment: there is not such a command in Hadoop, but I thing by using this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151008/linux-file-command-classifying-files you can implement it by yourself. only read some bytes and determine it is compressed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#count) doesn't have a command like `file` in Linux. Instead, reading the extensión might work: `if [ "$file" == "*.gz" ]`

Other options that requires coding in python or Java are:

- Managing `ZipFileInputFormat` to ensure that the zip file is a real compressed content.
- PySpark seems to have an option that can be used in the form `zipfile.ZipFile(in_memory_data, "r")`.

Both are addresed in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569788/how-to-open-stream-zip-files-through-spark/36511190).